# Ruby On Rails shoulda test error: Password digest missing on new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda

I am trying to write a test that validates the uniqueness of an email address.

This is for creating a new User account in Rails 4.0.0 and using has_secure_password.

I'm getting this error:

```
User should require case sensitive unique value for email
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email) }
     RuntimeError:
       Password digest missing on new record
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

`user_spec.rb`:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe User do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:full_name) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:password_digest) }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email) }
end
```

And here's the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :full_name, presence: true
  validates :password_digest, presence: true
end
```

What does the error message mean and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you supply a different email, does the error still get thrown?

Comment: What I'm doing is running `bundle exec rspec` without supplying an email address.  Here in the [docs for shoulda](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveModel:validate_uniqueness_of), it doesn't look like there's a requirement to enter an email address.  I'm not even sure where I'd enter an email address!

Comment: How are you generating the `User` object in the spec? Can you post your Factory/Fixtures code for this.

Comment: At this point I'm not generating a User, which could be part of the problem!  (60 seconds later...)  Rajesh, you are a genius!  I added `User.create(full_name: "Bob", email: "bob@bob.com", password: "bob", password_confirmation: "bob")` to run before each test and that fixed the problem.  Have my thanks and an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  I added a line to create a User object before each test and now the error went away.

```
describe User do        
  # this before section solved the problem
  before(:each) do
    User.create(
      full_name: "Bob",
      email: "bob@bob.com",
      password: "bob",
      password_confirmation: "bob"
    )
  end

  it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:full_name) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:password_digest) }

  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email) }
end
```

Comment: Agree that it solves the problem. But it is not good to create User for ALL your tests! Only validation on uniqueness requires existed record in DB (or it tries to create new record with options `:validate => false`). That is why you got error.
source http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveModel#validate_uniqueness_of-instance_method

Comment: Good point gotva.  I updated `user_spec.rb` to only do `User.create(...)` on `should validate_uniqueness_of(:email)`.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/371

Seems like the current solution is to create a new record prior to testing uniqueness. In short, here is the underlying issue:

> It appears that the Rails 4 version of `has_secure_password` adds a
>   before_create to ensure that `password_digest` is filled in; however,
>   the Rails 3 version does not have this check.